# Marshal void** c#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I try to use C dll in C#

```
typedef enum M_STATUS
{
// Unknown error. Should not be returned.
M_UNKNOWN = -1,
// Successful.
M_OK = 0
} M_STATUS;

M_STATUS WINAPI M_Create(LPVOID pTarget, LPVOID pDetour, LPVOID *ppOriginal);
```

In C# I have

```
[DllImport("Y:\\libs\\Min.x86.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern M_STATUS M_Create(IntPtr pTarget, IntPtr pDetour, ref IntPtr ppOriginal);
```

But I always get PinvokeStackImbalance Exception

Where is mistake?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are using CallingConvention.Cdecl with a function declared as WINAPI?

Comment: Also, in future, call ToString on the exception (or use the "copy exception details to the clipboard" link on the exception helper dialog) and put that in your question.

Comment: @Will: it's not actually exception, apparently. Either way, the full message is always nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding as an actual answer so it won't get lost.

The C function is declared as `WINAPI`, but the calling convention specified in the `DllImport` attribute is `Cdecl`. The conventions must match, so change it to either `StdCall` or `Winapi`.